# Findfirst, findnext listing files but not directories...?

Tags: delphi

the following code lists files but not directories

```
var 
rec : tsearchrec;
begin
findfirst('c:\test\*',faanyfile-fadirectory,rec);
        showmessage(rec.Name);
if findnext(rec) <> 0 then close else
showmessage (rec.Name);
end;
```

Comment: its just listing files not directories

Comment: and i put ''/*'' after c:/test but stackoverflow is not registering it i think something wrong with their server

Comment: Use "\\\*" to display "\\*". (even in comments - oh man!)

Comment: Omair, so what? What did you *expect* it to do when you subtracted `faDirectory`? What do you want it to do instead?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. You need to NOT exclude the directories, which you unfortunately do with your (-faDirectory)
2. You have to call FindClose when you're done.
3. You need to loop if you want to find everything in the directory

> ```
> var
>  rec : tsearchrec;
> begin
>   if FindFirst('c:\*', faAnyFile, rec) = 0 then
>   begin
>     repeat
>       ShowMessage(rec.Name);
>     until FindNext(rec) <> 0;
>     FindClose(rec);
>   end;
> end;
> ```

Comment: thanks, it is showing directories now but one more problem it is returning '..' and '.' in showmessage as well as files and folders, what are they i switched ''show hidden files option on'' but still cant see any '.' and '..' please help!

Comment: also i tried to show 'just directories' using '-faanyfile or fadirectory' in the attributes constant so than it does not show any files but just directory but it is still returning files

Comment: Omair, "." and ".." are directory entries, just like any other directory entry. You simply have to make sure your code can handle them. Also, you've probably realized that `FirstFirst` isn't very good at *excluding* results. Common practice is to use `FindFirst` and `FindNext` to enumerate *all* files and directories, and then check for the criteria you need in your own code and skip the ones you don't want.

Comment: but what are '.' and '..' for? are they directories and if they are why cant i access them even from command prompt? 2.is there a good alternative to findfirst?.3. while i dont know c++ does c++ have a good findfirst like function that is better at excluding results?

Comment: @Omair: "." is an alias for the current directory and ".." is the parent directory.  If you type "cd .." at the command prompt, you will move from the current directory to its parent.

Comment: @Omair. Please read the help entry for FindFirst. 
If you want only the directories, just use the flag faDirectory. Go and look at where it is defined and you'll see all available option that you can combine with or. (faAnyfile being already a combination in itself). 
Now as Rob explained, build the flag to encompass all the files you need and select those you really want inside the loop with an if condition meeting your specific criteria.

Comment: yes but why does findfirst list them as directories they are just DOS era functions...is something wrong with windows or delphi or am i making an issue out of an unimportant matter :)

Comment: Yes, you're making a mountain out of a molehill. Directories are stored as files on disk, and their contents are all the things you can get to from that directory. You can go from the directory to its parent, so each directory has a ".." entry. Likewise for the "." entry; you can choose to go nowhere. That's how file systems work. File systems are DOS-era things, since they existed during the DOS era. But we still use them today. I use them at the command line every day to refer to things relative to the current directory, and yet I haven't used DOS since the '90s.

Comment: @OmairIqbal: [read the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FindFirst) about how the listing filter actually works: "The Attr parameter specifies the special files to include **in addition to all normal files.**". In other words, `FindFirst()` always returns files, even if you only want folders. You need to test the `TSearchRec.Attr` field to determine if a reported entry is actually a file or a folder (and if you implement a recursive loop, make sure to ignore the "." and ".." folders or else your loop will recurse indefinately).

Answer (score 8):

[Read the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FindFirst) about how the filter actually works:

> The Attr parameter specifies the special files to include **in addition
>   to all normal files**.

In other words, `FindFirst()` always returns normal files, regardless of any filter criteria you specify. The `Attr` parameter merely includes **other** types of attributes into the base filter.  You need to test the `TSearchRec.Attr` field to determine if a reported entry is actually a file or a directory, eg:

```
if (rec.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0 then
  // item is a directory
else
  // item is a file
```

If you implement a recursive search loop, make sure to ignore the "." and ".." directories or else your loop will recurse indefinately:

```
procedure ScanFolder(const Path: String);
var  
  sPath: string;
  rec : TSearchRec; 
begin 
  sPath := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Path);
  if FindFirst(sPath + '*.*', faAnyFile, rec) = 0 then 
  begin
    repeat
      // TSearchRec.Attr contain basic attributes (directory, hidden,
      // system, etc). TSearchRec only supports a subset of all possible
      // info. TSearchRec.FindData contains everything that the OS
      // reported about the item during the search, if you need to
      // access more detailed information...

      if (rec.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0 then
      begin
        // item is a directory
        if (rec.Name <> '.') and (rec.Name <> '..') then
          ScanFolder(sPath + sr.Name);
      end
      else
      begin
        // item is a file
      end;
    until FindNext(rec) <> 0;
    FindClose(rec);
  end;
end; 

ScanFolder('c:\test');
```

Answer (score 4):

You explicitly excluded directories by stating " - faDirectory" in the flags parameter.

Answer (score 2):

What about findfirst('c:\test\*', **faanyfile**, rec);  // not faanyfile-fadirectory

Answer (score -2):

If you want all files and directories, just pass in faDirectory to findfirst.  It's going to already return you files.

Comment: I'm just going based on the voluminous documentation that's out there.

Comment: But why would you pass faDirectory when you can just pass faAnyFile, even if you can rely on the fact that this won't change? That's just not readable.